# Git Bash (Windows) not using PATH

Tags: python, windows, git, bash

I'm trying to set up `python` as an alias on my git bash and I've edited both my .bashrc and .bash_profile to have the alias. I've edited both files and I am still getting a command not found prompt within Git Bash:
[bash-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/839CL.png)

.bashrc and .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
# Enable tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash
alias python="~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe"
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure of the python path? `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe`

Comment: yup when I open file explorer and right click and go to properties that's the path

Comment: What if you use forward slashes? `alias python=~/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/python.exe`

Comment: The problem is definitely with your slashes as @janos said.

Comment: I wouldn't set an alias but rather a path to the python command. python.exe is found when typing python on Windows bash/mingw/whatever (or it would be very unpractical)

Comment: Do you have something against using `PATH` instead of an alias? That is, adding Python's parent directory to `PATH` ?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike python, backslashes not escaping anything are removed in bash.

So

```
alias python="~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe"
```

creates an alias to `~AppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython35python.exe`

Fix:

```
alias python="~/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/python.exe"
```

or just set the path (`.exe` suffix is supported on Windows flavours of `bash`)

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35
```

(so programs not having access to aliases/shell built-ins can still run `python` using `subprocess` or `exec`)